prevent blank lines from being numbered
I have a long list of items that I would like to be able to number without spending an hour numbering each piece by hand, and without every blank line also having a number.
Is there a way to do that?

Is this a programming-related question?

Yes. Because there is no way to do this in libreoffice unless using a macro or something like that.

Using Shift + Enter seems to be the only solution. But I have already typed many pages. The blank lines are numbered and it looks like some programming is required to remove them quickly. https://ask.libreoffice.org/t/prevent-blank-lines-from-being-numbered/40170

There is a way to do it in LibreOffice, no macro needed.

Do not check the 'Blank Lines' options here, when using the option which is found in the menu under Tools/Line Numbering:

